Calculating maximum of a function of several variables using a computer
Consider the function
$$f(r,s,t,a,b)=rst-e^{t^a}-e^{r^b}-s(\ln(s))^{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}}$$
where $r$, $t>0$ and $a$, $b$, $s\geq1.$
Is there any software that can calculate approximately the maximum point of this function with small error if there exist one?
I need to study this function to understand one inequality that is used in a article that I'm studying. For more reference, I'm trying to convince myself that the inequality in this post is true
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5012729/how-to-understand-the-last-step-of-the-proof-of-this-inequality?noredirect=1#comment10749951_5012729.
Thank you for the attention and every help will be appreciated!
Observation: I don't understand very much about algorithms and numerical methods, so if it is possible, I would love a detailed answer of commands used as well the detail of the software used.

I recommend studying the techniques for finding the maximum of a function of one variable before setting out to work in five dimensions.  Naturally one dimension is easier to visualize than five.  Two of your variables $r,t$ have an unbounded domain, and the other three are in $[1,\infty)$.  So there is something to be said to justify the claim that a maximum value exists.  It would improve your Question to say why you believe that claim.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=max%28+f%28r%2Cs%2Ct%2Ca%2Cb%29%29+where+f%28r%2Cs%2Ct%2Ca%2Cb%29%3Drst-exp%28t%5Ea%29-exp%28t%5Er%5Eb%29-s%28ln%28s%29%29%5E%281+%2Fa%2B+1%2Fb+%29&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22max%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22OptimizationWord%22%7D

@MPIchael Nice, there is some way in wolframalpha website to put some conditions while searching the maximum? for exemple $r,s,t,a,b \geq 1$

@MPIchael:  Your WolframAlpha input was f(r,s,t,a,b)=rst-exp(t^a)-exp(t^r^b)-s(ln(s))^(1 /a+ 1/b ), which has an extra "t^" in the third term.  We should try it without that.

Sorry. You are right.

I already have the answer, thank you for the help, the conclusion is: There is no global maxima or minima and the inequality I was trying to prove is actually false!
